# How can i get the user id from facebook url?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

```
How can i get the user id from facebook url and get the basic info ?
```

This will be possible if i use the http://www.facebook.com/[*username*]  '

Comment: More info, details on coding language and showing what you've researched and attempted. Right now this is not a good question

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the ID of a Facebook User, you need to authorize the User: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

After that, you will get an "App Scoped ID" for that User with this API endpoint: `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=[user-token]`

It is NOT possible to get the ID of a user by his username (or URL). Scraping is not allowed on Facebook - that i what some platforms do. But you do not need that ID anyway, you can just use the App Scoped ID instead.